# Is there a way to use promises when dealing with notifications via websocket?

Tags: javascript

Instead of registering my data to a callbacks array. I would like to define some promises. When notification comes from server it will *resolve* the promise.

I wrote *resolve*, but in fact promise will never be resolved, since we may have further notifications for same data.

Maybe right word is notify?
Can I use promise's notify for that behavior?

Comment: No, a Promise only resolves once. You want to use EventEmitters, also called Observables. In Nodejs you can use Streams in object mode

Comment: Well, I prefere using the observer pattern instead of EventEmitters. I currently working on angularjs, I think performance not so good